# 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Data.DataTable' using merge

Tags: c#, merge, datatable

Each time I use Merge() I have the following: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Can you please let me know what is wrong in my code ?

```
DataRow[] befdvd = toverify.Select("Date < '# " + dvddate + "#'");
DataRow[] aftdvd = toverify.Select("Date => '# " + dvddate + "#'");
foreach (DataRow dr in befdvd ) 
 dr[gl.EX_PRICE] = (double)dr[gl.EX_PRICE] * dvdfact;
 DataTable beff = befdvd.CopyToDataTable();
 DataTable Aftt = aftdvd.CopyToDataTable();
 toverify = beff.Merge(Aftt);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the error message.

`Merge()` returns `void`.
You can't assign that to a `DataTable` variable.

`Merge()` merges the second table into the first one; it does not create a new table.

Answer (score 4):

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx) DataTable.Merge() returns void:

```
public void Merge(
    DataTable table
)
```

So you cannot do that kind of assignment. Try this:

```
beff.Merge(Aftt);
toverify = beff;
```